# Python dict get function not doing the right thing?

Tags: python, dictionary

I thought that the `.get(key, default=?)` function will look at the `default` part only if `key` is not in the dict.

What I want to do is, see if a key exists in my main dictionary, if not, see if it exists in backup dictionary, and raise KeyError if it is neither in main or backup.

So, literally translating the above English statement to Python, I wrote: `val = mainDict.get(key, backupDict[key])`

This way, if `mainDict` doesn't have `key`, it will look it up in `backupDict` and raise exception if it's not there either, because I am not using `get` for `backupDict` lookup.

What is happening is, even before checking if `mainDict` has the `key` or not, Python is raising exception that it is not in `backupDict`. Yeah, it is not there, because it is there in `mainDict` !!

Why is this happening?

Comment: `get` only "looks at" the `default` if `key` isn't found, but the default is evaluated whether or not `get` looks at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments to a function call are evaluated before the call is made.  When you use `backupDict[key]` as an argument, that has to be evaluated so the result can be passed to `get`.  The `default` argument is always *evaluated*; it's just not always *returned*.

If you don't want to evaluate it, you could use some alternative formulation, like:

```
mainDict[key] if key in mainDict else backupDict[key]
```

This will only evaluate one or the other.

Comment: Good to know.  I thought 'default' is evaluated when needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.get#dict.get) function return `default` if the key is not in the dictionary. But `default` is evaluated.

You can use an intermediate dictionary like this.

```
main = dict(a=5, c=3)
backup = dict(a=6, b=9, c=4)

intermediate = dict(backup, **main)
print(intermediate['a'])
print(intermediate['b'])
```

You get:

```
5  # from the ``main``dict,
9  # from the ``backup dict``.
```

And with:

```
print(intermediate['d'])
```

You get an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
KeyError: 'd'
```